# Python - import only function from module

Tags: python

I have these two modules:

```
foo.py
bar.py
```

In `foo.py` I have a function `fn()` declared and a `print('test')`, outside of `fn()` context.

At the top of `bar.by`, I do:

```
from foo import fn
```

I can call `fn`, but I also print 'test', which I don't want.

---

Why? How can I import only what is *explicitly* imported from another module?

Comment: use ```if __name__ == "__main__": ``` at start of ```foo``` and all code after to be inside it to prevent python from running foo module when imported. Your way prevent python from importing extra names into your namespace

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should restructure foo.py to be:

```
def fn():
   # statements


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('test')
```

Now, when you import fn from foo in your other script, the print function will not be run.

Answer (score 0):

The way python works, importing will execute the target python file first. When you use `from X import Y` it still executes the file, but will only include the specific `Y` items into your namespace.

You can exclude `print("test")` by first checking `if __name__ == "__main__"` to see if the current file is being executed or just being used as an import.